# Unknown behavior justifying divs with css

Tags: html, css

There is Example 1 and Example 2. Example 2 is correct when in two rows and example 1 balls start to appear in wrong place, there is wasted space before first ball. Amount of green balls changes randomly. If it has balls in single row, it fails, if it has balls in two row it works... If the border between result and javascript fields are moved so that example 2 goes to single line it fails. So i need to get these balls starting in the beginning of the black border also in single row as it does when it is in two rows. Also "Example" text are need to stay in exact position they are in the example.

Also it would be great if the black box would end immediately after last ball in the row, now there can be almost ball length of wasted space.

Here is the examples: http://jsfiddle.net/xCG72/

**HTML**

```
<div class="kontti">
    <span class="tekstinpaikka">Example 1</span>
    <div class="teesi">
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">134234</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">2</div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="kontti">
    <span class="tekstinpaikka">Example 2</span>
    <div class="teesi">
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">10</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">20</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">30</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">40</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">10</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">20</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">30</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">40</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">10</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">20</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">30</div></div>
        <div class="kori"><div class="nnumero">40</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nnumero {
    background-color: #37A047;
    height:35px;
    width:auto;
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px;
    border-radius: 100px;

    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-right:auto;

    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.teesi {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:-10px;
    width:auto;
    overflow: hidden;

    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:purple;
}

.kontti {
    -moz-border-radius:9px;
    -webkit-border-radius:9px;
    border-radius:9px;  
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    float:left;
    width:auto;

    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;

    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}

.tekstinpaikka {
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
    top:-40px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    z-index:10;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow;

    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align:left;
    color:black;

    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.kori {
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;

    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;

    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```

Comment: Yes but row should split to two rows when space runs out.

Answer (score 0):

For your left margin behaviour on a single line, it is your text "exemple" falty.

Update your CSS class .tekstinpaikka :

```
.tekstinpaikka {
    position:absolute; /*MODIFIED*/
    left:15px;
    margin-top:-40px;/* MODIFIED PREVIOUSLY WAS TOP¨:*/
    width:auto;
    float:left; /*DELETED*/
    z-index:10;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align:left;
    color:black;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aUDn3/)**

Comment: Yes! Thank you! :) After looking too much own code it makes one blind! :) This did the trick! Thank you!